# How to tell website that electron is being used?

Tags: javascript, web, electron

I have an app that was created, using electron framework. This app just opens internet page. Is it possible to let my internet page know if user uses electron app? I need to show user a bit different version of page, if electron framework is being used.  Could you please propose a technique or method to do this? I will be very grateful for any information on this regard.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is likely adding a GET parameter to the opened website and deciding based on it's value/existence what content to deliver. Say your website is at `yourdomain.com/page`, point the electron app to `yourdomain.com/page?electron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use `window && window.process && window.process.type == 'renderer'`. It'll return true if it's running in electron and undefined if not.

See this github issue about it: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288.